# Can I invoke the composite's super's method in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, composite

Say inherited from a class, I can invoke `[self someMethod]` if someMethod is rewritten; I can also invoke `[super someMethod]`.

What if I use composition instead. Say I have porperty

```
@propery (nonatomic, strong) XXXController xxController;
```

Use `[self.xxController someMethod]` to invoke someMethod, but how to invoke `xxController`'s super version someMethod?

Comment: I'm quite sure that is not possible in Objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this*. Using composition does not allow you to break encapsulation.

*(It is actually possible to do this using runtime functions but you really, really, really shouldn't do that!)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.  And you don't want to.  Composition styles or not, an object should implement it's own methods, and call it's own `super` if necessary.

Instead, you should subclass `XXXController` to work how you want, calling `super` as necessary in that subclass.